# MySQL - Group comparison counts by day

Tags: mysql, group-by, comparison

I have the following query:

```
select
    DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%d %M') as day,
    count(*) as Total,
    count(content_sentiment = 0) as Neutral,
    count(content_sentiment < 0) as Negative,
    count(content_sentiment > 0) as Positive
from Master
where content_sentiment IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY DAY(created_at)
;
```

And that gives me:

```
day         total   Neautral    Negative    Positive
------------------------------------------------------------
01 August   9037    9037    9037    9037
02 August   6439    6439    6439    6439
03 August   5922    5922    5922    5922
04 August   5382    5382    5382    5382
```

The total value should be a sum of the positive, neutral and negative as is not im guessing as the query for each is getting a total for the entire table, rather than grouping by day.

How can I include a group by for each of the positive, neutral and negative values?

Comment: [`COUNT (<expr>)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) returns "*a count of the number of **non-NULL** values of expr in the rows retrieved by a SELECT statement.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need conditional aggregation:

```
...
count(*) as Total,
SUM(CASE WHEN content_sentiment = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Neutral,
SUM(CASE WHEN content_sentiment < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Negative,
SUM(CASE WHEN content_sentiment > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Positive
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    select
    DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%d %M') as day,
    count(*) as Total,
    sum(if(content_sentiment = 0,1,0)) as Neutral,
    sum(if(content_sentiment < 0,1,0)) as Negative,
    sum(if(content_sentiment > 0,1,0)) as Positive
from Master
where content_sentiment IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY DAY(created_at)
;
```